# Describe $(1,1,1,3)+lin \left\{ (4,-2,3,-2),(-2,0,0,1) \right\}$ with the system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I did this task and I need to check if I'm doing the right thing.
**My try:**
Let $((1,1,1,3)+lin \left\{ (4,-2,3,-2),(-2,0,0,1) \right\})=H$
Then $T(H)$: $$\begin{bmatrix}4 & -2 & 3 & -2 & | & 0 \\-2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & | & 0 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & -1 & | & 0 \\0 & -2 & 3 & 0 & | & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ So I have: $$ \begin{cases} 2x_{1}-x_{4}=0 \\ -2x_{2}+3x_{3}=0 \end{cases} $$
 $$\begin{cases} x_{4}=2x_{1} \\ x_{3}=\frac{2}{3} x_{2} \end{cases} $$That is why: $$T(H)=lin \left\{(1,0,0,2), (0,3,2,0)\right\}$$Hence:$$H:  \begin{cases} y_{1}+2y_{4}=b \\ 3y_{2}+2y_{3}=c \end{cases} $$ $$b=1 + 2 \cdot 3 =7$$ $$c=3 \cdot 1+ 2 \cdot 1=5$$ So my sollution:$$H:  \begin{cases} y_{1}+2y_{4}=7 \\ 3y_{2}+2y_{3}=5 \end{cases} $$

Is this the correct result?

Comment: wat is definition of "lin" which is in title and twice in question?

Comment: @coffeemath it is the same what "span"

Comment: I strongly recommend that you not use the same variable names for different things. In the first equations you derive, they represent the coefficients of the equations that you’re trying to find, but somewhere later on they switch to representing the coordinates of points that satisfy the later equations. This makes your reasoning harder to follow and can lead to errors.

Comment: @amd yes, you have right, I changed it

Comment: You can check your own work: does $(1,1,1,3)+\lambda(4,-2,3,-1)+\mu(-2,0,0,1)$ satisfy your two final equations?

Comment: One other suggestion for the future: add the corrections and reworking of the problem to your question as updates instead of replacing the original text. Doing the latter can make answers that you’ve gotten in the interim nonsensical and confuse future readers.

Comment: @amd ok, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can’t combine the equations as you’ve done at the end. The affine space that you’re trying to describe is two-dimensional, but the solution set of a *single* linear equation in four variables is *three*-dimensional. You need a system of at least two implicit linear equations to describe the set properly.

You’ve also made a computational error somewhere along the way: your system of equations is not satisfied by all of the points in the given set. If you substitute $(1,1,1,3)+\lambda(4,-2,3,-1)+\mu(-2,0,0,1)$ into the left-hand sides of the two equations, you get $23+6\lambda$ and $1-2\lambda$, respectively, instead of the required results. Observe that you’ve made an error right off the bat: the second row of your reduced matrix corresponds to the equation $-2x_2+3x_3=0$, i.e., you’ve mistakenly written $x_1$ instead of $x_2$. That error cascades through the rest of you calculations.

---

Your updated solution looks correct to me, but you can check it for yourself: does $(1,1,1,3)+\lambda(4,-2,3,-1)+\mu(-2,0,0,1)$ satisfy both equations?

Comment: Oh, I really sorry, it looks like I can not count because I'm making too many mistakes toda. I hope that this time I corrected all the errors. Is it correct in itself, apart from my mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Thr equations for T(H) that you should obtain when you abandon matrix notation are 
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l} 2x_1 - x_4 = 0 \\ -2x_2+3x_3 =0 \end{array}\right. $$
Can you continue from this point?

Comment: Oh, I really sorry for my mistakes. I edited my post.